# Initialize Failed with SICK LMS 5xx

Tags: ros, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I m using the ROS driver for SICK LMS511-10100 from here: https://github.com/pangfumin/lms511_laser

This returns me an error saying:

```
*** iirav@iirav:~$ rosrun laser_node laser_node       

Attempting to connect to Sick LMS 5xx @ 192.168.0.1:2111                                               A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout!                             A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout!                               [ERROR] [1496664746.220065882]: Initialize failed!
```

I also tried, setting one of the ethernet port to 192.168.0.10, but still ending up with the same error.

Can anyone help in getting this to work ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263224/initialize-failed-with-sick-lms-5xx/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-06-06**:
@sai I'm not familiar with this method of rangefinder. As stated below, I'd suggest you try pinging it to see if you can see it, otherwise check that that port in particular can be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you are able to ping the Lidar first before trying to use the driver. If you are unable to ping try changing network settings. If that doesn't help try using the SICK software on a windows computer to communicate with the LMS.

---

Originally posted by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) with karma: 151 on 2017-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0